# CSS Cursor with !important gets overridden by defaults

Tags: html, css

I have the following code that sets a class of `dragging-something` to the `html` element on a page on a trigger. The class does the following:

```
html.dragging-something {
    cursor: -moz-grabbing !important;
    cursor: -webkit-grabbing !important;
    cursor: grabbing !important;
}
```

That all works, until I move my mouse over another element that changes the cursor. (Like an input field)

How do I make it so my `dragging-something` class does not get overridden by anything else that might change the cursor?

jsFiddle (Problem): https://jsfiddle.net/BoxMan0617/jndukr86/

jsFiddle (Solution): https://jsfiddle.net/BoxMan0617/jxesdzqf/ (Thanks to @humble.rumble)

[Solved]

Comment: Can you provide some code to build a little context for the behavior. You may have a few options depending on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @ShotgunNinja yes, the class gets applied and the cursor changes. It's just when that cursor goes over another element that changes the cursor that the class stops working. OscillatingMonkey, I will attach a jsFiddle in a few.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to apply it to the elements contained within the HTML tag not just the HTML tag

```css
html.dragging-something * {
    cursor: -moz-grabbing !important;
    cursor: -webkit-grabbing !important;
    cursor: grabbing !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I personally try to avoid using `!important` as often as I can. Instead I give structuring and specificity of rules a shot: http://jsfiddle.net/vy599pa2/

```
<div class="move">
    <div class="pointer">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="pointer">
```

```
div {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    padding: 30px;
    background-color: grey;
    border: 2px solid black;
}

div div {
    padding: 0;
    background-color: lightblue;
}

div + div {
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.pointer,
.pointer * {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.move,
.move * {
    cursor: move;
}
```

Comment: Totally agree with you, but this is a top level change that MUST override any other changes. It is applied only on dragging events then removed. So it holds it's purpose.